# Horizontal recyclerview in tv dpad focus going cyclic on fast scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus, android-tv, d-pad

I am using a horizontal recyclerview in my tv project.I am setting focusable for the recycler view item.So with d pad I can move through.When I am doing normal key press everything works fine.But when I am trying to do a fast scroll with dpad after the focus reach last visible child focus moving to the first item and a cyclic focus change occurring.I saw some workarounds, but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Extend your layout manager and add the below snippet

```
@Override
public View onInterceptFocusSearch(View focused, int direction) {
    if (this.getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
        if (direction == View.FOCUS_RIGHT) {
            View view = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
            if (view == focused) 
                return focused;
        }
    }
    else if(getOrientation() == VERTICAL){
        if (direction == View.FOCUS_DOWN) {
            View view = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
            if (view == focused) 
                return focused;
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptFocusSearch(focused, direction);
}
```

Based on orientation i am handling the right focus and down focus. You can edit based on your needs.

Comment: I tried the solution but not work in my case with LinearLayoutManager.